# Groovy - XmlSlurper - read attributes into a Map

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

```
<racebet amount="8.89" id="6852465" bettype="K" instance="1" type="csf" />
```

What is the best way to create a map containing the attributes as keys and the corresponding values?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given:

```
def xml = '<racebet amount="8.89" id="6852465" bettype="K" instance="1" type="csf" />'
```

You can simply do:

```
def attrmap = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).attributes()
```

Comment: Wow, great. The documentation for XMLSlurper lacks a lot: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper

Comment: Same is applicable if `XmlParser` is used.

Comment: @saravana_pc You should be looking at [GPathResult](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html) Api or [Node](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Node.html) Api instead, because the parsed result is one of those when XmlSlurper ot XmlParser is used respectively.

Comment: In this case, it's a [NodeChild](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.html) -- `assert new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ).getClass().name == 'groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild'`